# Workbook tab won't open in VBA Editor

Tags: excel, vba

I have weird bug - then I open VBA Editor I can edit and create macros for sheets just fine, but then I try to edit macros for Workbook (create on_open event) I can't access ThisWorkbook tab in VBA Editor. Then I click it - nothing happens. What causing this problem? If I create new Excel workbook I can access this part with no problem (but that is not an option, since it would be to much work to move everything to new workbook).

EDIT: I turned off SOLVER add-in and the problem is gone. But I am still baffled why it was happening and how to avoid this problem in the future, since I sometimes need SOLVER add-in enabled.

EDIT 2: After writing desired routines for on_open and before_close events I restarted my Workbook to test it out. Events did not activated and I am locked from Workbook tab in VBA Editor again. Strangely everything worked fine then I tested it on older Excel version (MS Office 2013, version I am working with - MS Office 2016 version 1912 ) in other PC.

Comment: Looks just like an Excel bug or corrupt installation of Office. Which version are you using? Make sure it is the latest build (just in case update). • Test if this happens on the same version with other computers (if it happens it is a bug, report it to Microsoft or wait for them to fix it). If it only happens on your computer, try re-installing Office completely.

Comment: I am using MS Office Professional 2016 version 1912 of Excel. After testing it on other Excel version I came in conclusion that it is indeed some kind of a bug, but it affects only this Workbook (since other Workbooks works fine). Strangely enough after writing desired code and restarting workbook I am locked again form that VBA part in visual editor and code won't start on my computer then launching Workbook, but on the other PCs it seems working fine.

Comment: *"but it affects only this Workbook"* does this specific workbook work on other computers? If so try re-installing Office on the computer where it is not working.

Comment: I only faced this problem on this specific workbook and it works on other computers (as far as I managed to test it, have access to only few more). Thankfully this update was last one of the planned updates so I will leave it as it is, as long as it works on other computers and only reinstall Office if I ever encounter this bug again in the future.